# Crontab not working in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, cron, crontab

I installed it in a machine at work and it wouldn't do anything, no matter what I did. So now I have it on virtualbox at home and it also doesn't work. Here's what I'm trying to do:

Have a file on /home/john/Desktop called test.sh. Its contents:

#!/bin/bash
echo "Bing!" > /tmp/cronjob

Have done a `chmod 777 test.sh` and can run it. Listing it shows as rwx for users/group/global. Then I do a `crontab -e` and add the following line:

`* * * * * john /home/john/Desktop/test.sh`

But it doesn't work. The file is never written. I've also tried using a specific time (for example, it's 9 PM so I set the hour to 05 21 and wait) but it doesn't work as well. I've also tried without the user "john" in the crontab but no dice. I tried using `crontab -e -u john` too. Nothing works.

Doing a `service cron status` I get that it is started/running. I've tried restarting it as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, if I need to run some commands as root I'm supposed to use it with `crontab -e -u <username> right`?

Answer (score 2):

Just to be sure:

*crontab -e*

then

> 30 21 * * * /home/john/Desktop/test.sh

EDIT: I mean that you don't need no "john" beside the time section of cron and the path to the command.

Answer (score 2):

There are three different ways to use cron.

1. Putting scripts in the /etc/cron.hourly , /etc/cron.daily , /etc/cron.weekly or /etc/cron.monthly folders
   The system will then run those at the scheduled time with root privileges
2. Editing /etc/crontab
   This takes a syntax like the one you were trying to use in *crontab -e*, because here you can specify which user should be responsible for the scheduled job, in your case, john.
3. The crontab command, which saves a cron tab for the user that made the job in /var/spool/cron/crontabs

If you are using the third method, you don't need to tell it you are john, it already knows. You can however tell it with the -u flag to save the job in someone elses cron tab.
Using the third method, you do not need to have the *john* in `* * * * * john /home/john/Desktop/test.sh`

Comment: There's also the ``/etc/cron.d`` you didn't mention.

Answer (score 1):

```
* * * * * john /home/john/Desktop/test.sh
```

The "john" here is wrong. Only the system crontab has a user name field; the per-user crontabs which you edit with crontab -e do not have it (the user is implicit). Just leave it out.

> Also, if I need to run some commands
>   as root I'm supposed to use it with
>   crontab -e -u  right?

No, if you want a cronjob to run with root rights just do

```
sudo crontab -e
```

(or put it into the system crontab, with user name "root").

Comment: system crontab? could you explain? would it be right to use crontab -e -u root?

Comment: @john p: Yes, and no. If you've editing the files in /etc/cron.whatever, then YES, you need a user name. If you're logged in as john, and editing your default crontab with crontab -e, then NO, you don't need a username.